# Sum of reciprocals of primes dividing Mersenne numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Then it has been proven by [Erdős](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1971-14.pdf) that $$\sum_{p\mid 2^{n}-1}\frac1{p} \ll \log \log \log n.$$ Let $c<1$ be a positive constant. Then can we prove that $$\sum_{p\mid 2^{n}-1}\frac1{p^{c}}\ll \frac{\log ^{1-c} n}{\log \log n}?$$

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Why does it seem to you that the argument should apply? Is it a homework perchance?

Comment: I apologise for the comment. I had some arguments in mind that I thought would translate. But those have a flaw. This is a problem I need to tackle in my research.

Comment: Probably this can be obtained using Abel's summation formula.